# Android MediaPlayer with LocalSocket not working

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, unix-socket, localsocket

I am trying to play media from LocalSocket using MediaPlayer. The stream is of type MPEG-TS, which is availale in a LocalSocket input stream

Following code tries to `setDataSource` to the `FileDescriptor` of `LocalSocket`, but failes.

```
LocalSocket wsIns = fileThread.getReadSocket();
p = new MediaPlayer();
p.setDisplay(holder);
FileDescriptor fd = wsIns.getFileDescriptor();
Log.e("TS","is valid ? "+fd.valid());
p.setDataSource(fd ,0, fileThread.getLength());
```

setDataSource fails with following exception.

```
10-13 17:21:31.510: W/System.err(6472): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
10-13 17:21:31.510: W/System.err(6472):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
10-13 17:21:31.510: W/System.err(6472):     at com.example.test.TSRenderActivity.surfaceCreated(TSRenderActivity.java:94)
```

The debug logs suggest that the error is primarily due to [this](http://androidxref.com/4.1.2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerService.cpp#835), where `fstat` on the LocalSocket's file descriptor returns size of the file as 0.

But if I try `wsIns.getInputStream().available()` this api gives non zero number of bytes available.

Note : 
The same error on using `p.setDataSource(fp);`